# Not sure if I have to use class attribute or instance attribute

Tags: python, class, attributes, nltk, tokenize

I'm a beginner in python so I already apologize for the very basic question.

I have an assignment where I have to create a list of sentences and tokens from a given text and save them as attributes in the class. Further, I have to make sure that the tokens are saved in a data structure that still represents the sentences (as in: I can still see if a token stands at the beginning of a sentence or not).

I know how to create the class and, in theory, how to tokenize the text using NLTK.

```
class Text:
    sentences = []
    sentences.append(sent_tokenize(text))
    tokens = [word_tokenize(text)]
    tokens.append()

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.raw_text = text
```

In the example above I used (as far as my understanding goes) class attributes. However, I'm not sure if I really have to code it like that or if I have to use instance attributes.

I'm very grateful for any help!

Comment: You can't refer to variables like `text` outside the method. The code outside the methods is executed when the class is defined, not when you create an instance, and it doesn't have access to the `text` parameter variable. Move the code that updates `sentences` into the `__init__()` method.

Comment: Whether `sentences` should be a class or instance attribute depends on how it's used. Is it supposed to be shared by all the instances, or is it specific to each instance?

Answer (score 0):

The point of instance attributes is so that you can have more than one *instance* of the class, each with its own attribute values.

To illustrate this, imagine an Employee class:

```
class Employee:
    company = "ACME Corp"

    def __init__(self, name, id_number, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.id_number = id_number
        self.salary = salary

bob = Employee("Bob", 1, 10000)
alice = Employee("Alice", 2, 15000)
craig = Employee("Craig", 3, 18000)
```

This class has a `company` class attribute that is shared among all instances (because we assume all employees work for this company), and it also has `name`, `id_number`, and `salary` attributes that are specific to individual employees.

So, to answer your question, it depends on how you will *use* the Text class.  If you plan on having multiple instances at once, each with their own separate texts, then it sounds like you need instance attributes.

But if you will only have one instance of the class, then class attributes will do the job.